# Combine two rows into one?

Tags: c#, sql, database, select, group-by

May I know the code to combine this two database item? I mean the `TimeOUT` from the second line would be in the first `TimeOUT` so it will be not null when I cast this out to the listview.

Please see image here:

[image]

I am using C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this dataset, aggregation would do:

```
select
    empID,
    firstName,
    lastName,
    date,
    min(timeIn) timeIn,
    max(timeOut) timeOut
from mytable
group by
    empID,
    firstName,
    lastName,
    date
```